# error while generalizing my variadic template function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I implemented the template function below using variadic, but I am having difficulties in making it more generic. I am using MS VS C++ 2017.

This function essentially checks if an integer value is one of the values provided int templates argument. In theory should be equivalent to a list of logical OR.

```
template<int TFirst, int...TArgs>
constexpr bool foo(int&& a)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(TArgs) > 0)         
        return a == TFirst || foo<TArgs...>(std::forward<int>(a));    
    return a == TFirst;
}

int iii = 3;
assert(foo<1, 2, 3>(std::forward<int>(iii)); // ok!
```

I would like to make this function even more generic using other numeric types like double or class enums or even objects.

I tried the code below. It builds  with integers, but NOT with doubles.

```
 template<typename T>
 struct check
 {
     template<T TFirst, T...TArgs>
     static constexpr bool foo(T&& a)
     {
         if constexpr (sizeof...(TArgs) > 0)
            return a == TFirst || foo<TArgs...>(std::forward<T>(a));
         return a == TFirst;
     }
 };

// test
int iii = 3;
double ddd = 4.0;

check<int>::foo<1, 2, 3>(std::forward<int>(iii));  // ok
check<double>::foo<1.0, 2.0, 3.0>(std::forward < double >(ddd )); // non ok
```

Error I have with double is

```
 error C2993: 'T': illegal type for non-type template parameter 'TFirst'
 error C2672: 'check<double>::foo': no matching overloaded function found
```

Is there any fix this or better way to make my function more generic?

Comment: You can't use double values as template parameters, see the linked question for background information. There's no way around it, you will have to come up with some alternative approach that does not involve double template parameters.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Can we not close this as a dupe but instead acknowledge they can't do what they have because of the dupe so how can they work around it.

Comment: I see..so is like using literals string for template..interesting. I didn't think about it at all.Thanks for pointing me to the right response; I googled for similar questions but I was not able to find anything like that.

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile FWIW, you could write the code like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7de9a391d49ce51d)

Comment: @Nathan. Wow! That's pretty hard-core! I never seen using the '...' like that? In fact I don't understand much how your function works (sorry). I am used to  recursively call of a variadic template with less argument...I have no idea how your  function is expanding.   Can you point me to some useful tip for further reading or investigation?  I found this usage truly amazing.

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile I used a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).  It makes life soooooooo much easier.  The gist of it is that `(find == in)` is the expression we want to do, and then we will or that with each additional `in`, so it expands out to `(find == in1) || (find == in2) || ... || (find == inN)`

Comment: @NathanOliver Sir, I thank you very much for this input. It is a very interesting topic I was not aware and worth to explore. Have a great day!